# Elastic search Query based on input array of doc ids

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have an index "jobs" on elastic search, from where I want to fetch the records in a way that all the documents with the ids, I input come in the priority of the order in the array and all the other records are in the order of latest one first.

So let's say I have the job records in the index, from 1-100, with the 100th job being the latest, and I give the
$jobIds = [6,22,98,16] as the priority then the array of jobs return to me should be in order :
[6,22,98,16,100,99,97,96 ..., 1]
I am using this query :

```
$jobIds = [6,22,98,16];
$params = [
            'index' => 'jobs',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'function_score' => [
                        'query' => [
                            'match_all' => (object) [],
                        ],
                        'functions' => [
                            [
                                'filter' => [
                                    'terms' => [
                                        '_id' => $jobIds,
                                    ],
                                ],
                                'script_score' => [
                                    'script' => [
                                        'source' => 'return 9999 - params.ids.indexOf(doc["_id].value)',
                                        'params' => [
                                            'ids' => $jobIds,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            [
                                'filter' => [
                                    'match_all' => (object) [],
                                ],
                                'script_score' => [
                                    'script' => [
                                        'source' => "return 0;",
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'score_mode' => 'sum',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
$response = Elasticsearch::search($params);
```

This code is in PHP(laravel). I have just written the query to sort the priority jobIds, but it does not return in the order of input array. I don't know where I am wrong in this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you filter by jobIds, then you don't have to filter in script,

```
    {
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "functions": [
                    {
                        "filter": {
                            "terms": {
                                "_id": [
                                    6,
                                    22,
                                    98,
                                    16
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "script_score": {
                            "script": {
                                "source": "9999 - Integer.parseInt(doc['_id'].value)"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "filter": {
                            "match_all": {}
                        },
                        "script_score": {
                            "script": {
                                "source": "return 0"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "score_mode": "sum"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Though this did not give correct order,
"source" : "9999 - ids.indexOf(Integer.parseInt(doc['_id'].value))" worked.

But since you help me in correcting the code to parse the value as integer, accepting it.

Thank you :)